# How to fix offset in Kendo UI 5 dropdowns when page is translated by Google translate?

Tags: kendo-ui, calendar, offset, dropdownbox

If page is translated by Google translate when Kendo UI Dropdown (or Kendo UI Calendar) box appear 40 px lower.
I can fix it easy it there are only one or two Kendo UI dropdown box on the page.

I check if value of 'body' css 'top' become equal to 40px,
and change Dropdown position.

```js
 var pixelsTopBody = $('body').css('top');
     var kendoCalendarPosition = (parseInt($('.k-animation-container:eq(0)').css('top')) - 40) + "px";

     if (pixelsTopBody == '40px') {
         $('.k-animation-container:eq(0)').css('top', kendoCalendarPosition);
     }
```

Kendo UI element with class .k-animation-container does not exist on the page before I click the button with class .k-select. If there are only 2 Dropdown on the page and I start clicking the second one, then there will be only one element with class .k-animation-container on this stage. To fix it I need to check length of $('.k-animation-container').length. And everything works fine:

```js
$("body").delegate(".k-select:eq(1)", "click", function () { 
                    
    var pixelsTopBody = $('body').css('top');
                     
    if ($('.k-animation-container').length == 1 && pixelsTopBody == '40px') {
        var kendoCalendarPosition = (parseInt($('.k-animation-container:eq(0)').css('top')) - 40) + "px";
        $('.k-animation-container:eq(0)').css('top', kendoCalendarPosition);
    }
    if ($('.k-animation-container').length == 2 && pixelsTopBody == '40px') {
        var kendoCalendarPosition = (parseInt($('.k-animation-container:eq(1)').css('top')) - 40) + "px";
        $('.k-animation-container:eq(1)').css('top', kendoCalendarPosition);
    }
                     
});
```

But what to do if there are 5 Kendo UI Dropdowns on the page? The above approach does not work in this case.  May be solution is to make all element with class .k-animation-container to exist on page load or after the first click? How to do it with Kendo UI?

I can fix offset by id of Kendo UI DropdownLists. For example if the 5th DropdownList has id= "ddlDownlineWithPendingOrDeclinedOrders".

```js
$("body").delegate(".k-input:eq(4)", "click", function () {
    
    var pixelsTopBody = $('body').css('top'); 

    if ($('#ddlDownlineWithPendingOrDeclinedOrders-list').length == 1 && pixelsTopBody == '40px') {
        
        var kendoCalendarPosition = (parseInt($('#ddlDownlineWithPendingOrDeclinedOrders-list').parent().css('top')) - 40) + "px";
        $('#ddlDownlineWithPendingOrDeclinedOrders-list').parent().css('top', kendoCalendarPosition); 
    }  
});
```

But I want to find more general approach to fix offset for 5 Kendo UI DropdownLists then translated by Google.